# Could someone show me how to solve a differential equation in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have the following equation:
$$A^2\space t^2\space dt^2=-c^2\space dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{1-K\space r^2}$$
I understand how linear equations are solved in Mathematica, but can someone walk me through the solution to this equation for r?

Comment: If `ode` is a linear ODE, then you use `DSolve[ode, r, t]`; but if `ode` is a *nonlinear* ODE, something different happens and you use `DSolve[ode, r, t]`.  Of course, it looks the same to the user. The difference is internal and hidden from the user, which aligns with the design decision for *Mathematica* to make such choices for the user automatically as well as in most cases correctly. (The non-difference in the approaches probably suggests to the community that you haven't tried to solve it and explains the response.)

Comment: I am still trying to figure out which is the dependent variable and which is the independent variable. Since you have both $dt^2$ and $dr^2$ in there and I see no $d^2 r$ and no $d^2 t$. But if it is $r(t)$ and not $t(r)$, and $dr^2$ is typo and meant to be $d^2 r$, then try `ClearAll[A, t, c, k, r];
ode = A^2 t^2 == -c^2 + D[r[t], {t, 2}]/(1 - k r[t]^2);
sol = DSolve[ode, r[t], t]` but Mathematica can't solve this analytically. You could try `NDSolve` in this case. But need initial conditions and need numerical values for all parameters.

Comment: @MichaelE2 But WRI can increase the count of functions it has by breaking `DSolve` to  `DSolveLinear` and `DSolveNonlinear`. It can even add more, by making seperate solvers for ODE's and for PDE's so we have additional `PDESolveLinear` and `PDESolveNonlinear`. Also make a version of each above for Numerical solvers, by adding `N` the name of each.  This is not far fetched. We already have `AsymptoticDSolveValue` and `DSolveValue` and `NDSolveValue`, `ParametericNDSolveValue`, `NDSolve`, `ParametricNDSolve`. WRI can easily double the number of functions it has this way.

Comment: @Nasser It already has such functions, which is what I was hinting at in my comment.  Examine ``? DSolve`*``.  But putting them at the top level runs counter to design principles.

Comment: @Nasser - Those are squares, not second derivatives.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Yes, I agree, better to have one top level function only.  But Mathematica still have so many top level functions that could be all collapsed into much fewer functions. But this is for another discussion.

Answer (score 3):

> Those are squares, not second derivatives

$$A^2\space t^2\space dt^2=-c^2\space dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{1-K\space r^2}$$

In that case, `DSolve` can do it.  Dividing both sides by $(dt)^2 \neq 0$ gives

$$
A^2 t^2=\frac{r'(t)^2}{1-k r(t)^2}-c^2
$$

```
ClearAll[A, t, c, k, r];
ode = A^2 t^2 == -c^2 + (D[r[t], t])^2/(1 - k r[t]^2);
sol = DSolve[ode, r[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sorry, it took me a second to digest the result. This looks good.  I'll try it out with some real data later.  Thank you.

Comment: $dt$ and $dr$ are differentials.